# Rearrangement rows to columns on linux

Tags: sed, tr

I want that rows to rearrangement to columns with spaces between the strings.

```
q9I6OEFg003411
q9I5IHv5006818
q9I6Gi6P024439
q9I5RoA0019541
```

Expected view:

```
q9I6OEFg003411 q9I5IHv5006818 q9I6Gi6P024439 q9I5RoA0019541
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tr` to translate `<newline>` to `<space>`:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file
```

---

Also in `sed`:

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;${g;s/\n/ /g;p}' file
```

---

In `awk`:

```
awk -vORS=' ' 1 file
```

---

If file is small, you can use `cat`:

```
echo `cat file`
```

---

If you know `vim`:

```
:%s/\n/ /
```

---

*maybe more ...*

Answer (score 1):

Using paste command:

```
paste -sd" " file
```

d option to set delimiter.